# Probability that two voters voted for a different party.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Suppose a set of $N = \{1, 2, . . . , n\}$
> political parties participated in an election; n ≥ 2. Suppose further that there were a total of $V$ voters, each of whom voted for exactly one party. Each party $i\in N$ received a total of $V_i$ votes, so that V = $\displaystyle\sum_i^n V_i$. Given the vector $(V_1, V_2, . . . , V_n)$, whose elements are the total number of votes received by the $n$ different parties, define $P_1 (V_1, V_2, . . . , V_n)$ as the probability that two voters drawn at random with replacement voted for different parties and define $P_2 (V_1, V_2, . . . , V_n)$ as the probability that two voters drawn at random without replacement voted for different parties.
> Find the ratio $\frac{P_1}{P_2}$ as a function of $V.$

I tried solving $P_1$ as $1 \cdot \frac{V - V_i}{V}$. My reasoning was you can pick anyone as the first person with probability $1.$ Then for the second person, you have $V-V_i$ candidates who did not vote for the same party as the first person and thus the resulting probability. I solved for $P_2$ in a similar way.

I feel my approach is wrong, but I'm stuck with how to proceed. Could someone please guide me?

Comment: The term $\frac{V-V_i}{V}$ only works if the first person chose party $i$. So you should replace the $1$ by $\frac{V_i}{V}$ and sum the product over all $i$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much sense now that I see it like that.

Comment: You should also double check your denominator depending on whether you are sampling with/without replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Given $(V_1,\dots,V_n)$, the probability that a randomly chosen voter voted for party $i$ is $V_i/V$. If we consider the situation with the replacement, probability that two randomly chosen voters both voted for party $i$ is $(V_i/V)^2$ due to independence. Hence
$$
P_2=1-\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{V_i}{V}\right)^2
$$
For $P_1$ it's slightly more complicated: the conditional probability that the second voter voted for $i$ is then $(V_i-1)/V$ so
$$
P_1=1-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{V_i(V_i-1)}{V^2}.
$$

Comment: $P_2$ should be the probability w/o replacement while $P_1$ should be the probability w/ replacement. Also, I think you should have $V(V-1)$ in the probability calculation w/o replacement. Lastly, you should be subtracting your answers from $1$ since the probability that you're computing are for the complementary events

Comment: corrected, thanks!